# What is the time complexity of LinkedList.getLast() in Java?

Tags: java, performance, collections, big-o

I have a private LinkedList in a Java class & will frequently need to retrieve the last element in the list.  The lists need to scale, so I'm trying to decide whether I need to keep a reference to the last element when I make changes (to achieve O(1)) or if the LinkedList class does that already with the getLast() call.

**What is the big-O cost of LinkedList.getLast()** and **is it documented?** (i.e. can I rely on this answer or should I make no assumptions & cache it even if it's O(1)?)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is O(1) because the list is doubly-linked.  It keeps references to both head and tail.

From documentation:

> Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

Comment: It's not only doubly linked, it's also cyclic.

Comment: the "cyclic" comment by helpermethod clearly answer the question.

Comment: @helpermethod, thanks. Today I have learnt how a LinkedList is organized. Earlier I thought it keeps reference to the last element.

Answer (score 5):

It is O(1) and you should not have to cache it. The getLast method simply returns `header.previous.element`, so there is no computation and no traversal of the list. A linked list slows down when you need to find elements in the middle it since it starts one end and moves one element at a time.

Answer (score 2):

From the Java 6 source code:

```
* @author  Josh Bloch
 * @version 1.67, 04/21/06
 * @see     List
 * @see     ArrayList
 * @see     Vector
 * @since 1.2
 * @param <E> the type of elements held in this collection
 */

public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    private transient Entry<E> header = new Entry<E>(null, null, null);
    private transient int size = 0;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        header.next = header.previous = header;
    }

...

    /**
     * Returns the first element in this list.
     *
     * @return the first element in this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E getFirst() {
    if (size==0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return header.next.element;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the last element in this list.
     *
     * @return the last element in this list
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if this list is empty
     */
    public E getLast()  {
    if (size==0)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    return header.previous.element;
    }

...

}
```

so that's O(1) for both `getFirst()` & `getLast()`

Answer (score 1):

From the [LinkedList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) docs:

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

It should be O(1) since a doubly-linked list will have a reference to its own tail.  (Even if it doesn't *explicitly* keep a reference to its tail, it will be O(1) to *find* its tail.)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of LinkedList.getLast() leaves no doubts - it's an O(1) operation.
However, I didn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: You might have to look into the Java Source Code for implementation details like Yaneeve did. You can attach java core lib source code to IDE.