# Linked List Descending Iteration with Insertion

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to iterate backwards through a Java linked list starting at the end.
Java's LinkedList has a method descendingIterator() that return an iterator that goes backwards.
However, I also want to be able to dynamically make constant-time insertions into the list wherever I am during the iteration. The descendingIterator() method does not return a ListIterator, so it can't perform insertions.
Is there any built-in way to do this in Java, or would i just have to make my own implementation?

Comment: Of course, I could call LinkedList#listIterator() and pass it the length of the list, but I believe that would run in linear time, which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.listIterator(list.size()-1);
```

is probably what you are looking for. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), it should not run in linear time:

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked
>   list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from
>   the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

So you can consider that the LinkedList has direct access to its last element.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765764/734151

You might want to check execution time to validate this.